# Abrir calendário a partir de um link

Tags: android, html5, iphone

Vi muitas formas diferentes de fazer isso, mas nenhuma funciona

Preciso colocar um link no meu site, onde quando clicar, abrir a agendar para a pessoa salvar na agenda dela

assim como o tel: mailto:, vi algumas coisas como calendar: calshow:, mas nenhuma funciona

Tentei criar ics e fazer download, porem no android não funciona se não tiver algum programa terceiro para fazer handle do ics

Alguem ja passou por isso? Alguma dica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que achei a minha propria resposta. Infelizmente não sei se posso responde-la, mas se nao puder, peço aos moderadores que corrijam e me instruam para que eu possa entender melhor

Bem, no iOS temos o webcal, como disse anteriormente. Montando links assim:

```
<a href="webcal://192.168.1.102/scripts/apptest/teste.ics">Agendar</a>
```

O iOS abre direitinho o evento

Para resolver esse problema, no shouldOverrideUrlLoading do meu webview, eu verifico se a URL possui o webcal, e abro um novo intent para o calendário, assim eu baixo o ICS e monto um calendário. Sei que existem maneiras melhores de dar o parse no ICS, mas segue o código que utilizei

De qualquer forma, agora tenho o mesmo HTML funcionando para ambos os dispositivos

```
// Verifica se começa com o protocolo de calendario (webcal para manter padrão com ios)
        if(url.startsWith("webcal")) {

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
            try {
                // Cria o link para o ICS
                URL urla = new URL(url.replace("webcal", "http"));

                // Coloca em buffer todo o texto
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urla.openStream()));
                String str;

                // Inicia o calendario e percorre linha à linha
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    /*
                        Verificar de não ter espaços entre o :
                        Não usar Z no final do datetime
                     */

                    // Verifica data de inicio
                    if(str.contains("DTSTART:")) {
                        // Cria o formato da data e da o parse
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
                        Date date = format.parse(str.replace("DTSTART:", ""));

                        // Adiciona o parametro
                        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, (date.getTime()));
                    }

                    // Verifica data de fim
                    else if(str.contains("DTEND:")) {
                        // Cria o formato da data e da o parse
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
                        Date date = format.parse(str.replace("DTEND:", ""));

                        // Adiciona o parametro
                        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, (date.getTime()));
                    }

                    // Verifica o titulo
                    else if(str.contains("SUMMARY:")) {
                        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, str.replace("SUMMARY:", ""));
                    }

                    // Verifica o organizador
                    else if(str.contains("ORGANIZER:")) {
                        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER, str.replace("ORGANIZER:", ""));
                    }

                    // Verifica o local
                    else if(str.contains("LOCATION:")) {
                        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, str.replace("LOCATION:", ""));
                    }

                    // Verifica o descrição
                    else if(str.contains("DESCRIPTION:")) {
                        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, str.replace("DESCRIPTION:", ""));
                    }
                }

                // Fecha a conexão
                in.close();

                // Inicia o intent do calendário
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.d("Log", "Erro: " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Log", "Erro: " + e);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.d("Log", "Erro: " + e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Log", "Erro: " + e);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
  if (window.addtocalendar)
    if (typeof window.addtocalendar.start == "function") return;
  if (window.ifaddtocalendar == undefined) {
    window.ifaddtocalendar = 1;
    var d = document,
      s = d.createElement('script'),
      g = 'getElementsByTagName';
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.charset = 'UTF-8';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = ('https:' == window.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://addtocalendar.com/atc/1.5/atc.min.js';
    var h = d[g]('body')[0];
    h.appendChild(s);
  }
})();
```

```html
<link href="http://addtocalendar.com/atc/1.5/atc-style-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="addtocalendar atc-style-blue">
  <var class="atc_event">
    <var class="atc_date_start">2016-05-04 12:00:00</var>
    <var class="atc_date_end">2016-05-04 18:00:00</var>
    <var class="atc_timezone">Europe/London</var>
    <var class="atc_title">Star Wars Day Party</var>
    <var class="atc_description">May the force be with you</var>
    <var class="atc_location">Tatooine</var>
    <var class="atc_organizer">Luke Skywalker</var>
    <var class="atc_organizer_email">luke@starwars.com</var>
  </var>
</span>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AddToCalendar/Df86Z/

Livraria: http://addtocalendar.com/

Comment: A ideia é muito boa. Porem pelo que eu testei por aqui ele deu a opção para o usuário adicionar no calendário mais conveniente. Dai se o usuário nao sabe o que ele tem, ele nao sabe o que fazer. Outro problema é que se no celular ele nao usa google calendar, ele não funciona. O bom mesmo seria se ao abrir o .ics (por exemplo) ele perguntasse aquele famoso "abrir como", ou algo assim sabe? porem ics não funciona no android

Comment: Ao abrir o .ics ele vai perguntar qual o calendário, que quer mas mesmo assim é necessário que o utilizador execute o ficheiro.. Podes simplesmente ver qual o tipo de aparelho a aceder ao site e a partir daí reencaminhas para o calendário predefinido do mesmo. Resposta editada.

Comment: Se tentar abrir o ICS no android, verá que ele aparecerá: "cannot open file"